# Is there a way to make an ion-modal-sheet to snap the header in Ionic V6

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm currently developing an app using Ionic V6 and i'm figured out if it was possible to make an ion-modal-sheet snap the header when it fully swiped like the Uber eats application ?

[image: uber eats modal sheet exemple]

Thanks in advance for your answers and have a nice day !

Comment: You can but u need to achieve it in ur way using js and editing values of css within the js part..so for example when breakpoint reaches 0.6 then change the height or background of the header or etc.. and at the same time change the breakpoint to become 0.8 so in this way u can achieve things

Comment: Hmm ok, i understand, i'll try something and if it work i'll make an answer with my code. Thank you !

Comment: sounds great, start with breakpoints and after u become near thing that u want to achieve, then change things to pixels instead of depending on breakpoints since breakpoints will not give you accurate design..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who wondering how to do it, here's how i managed to get something similar:

first of all i've added an id to my header (my ion-header is wrapped inside a component called header) if your header is always in the same page of where you're creating the modal, use a template reference variable instead of an id:

```html
<header
 id="getHeight"
 [title]="'Solutions disponibles'"
 [displayGoBack]="true"></header>
```

then i've created a helper to:

- Get the height of the header (can be different between iOS and Android)
- Get the body height
- Use the body height and the header height to return the height my modal should have in px and in %

```ts
export const getContentHeight = (): any => {
  const header = document.querySelector('#getHeight');
  const body = document.querySelector('body');
  if (body && header) {
    const percent = (100 - (header.clientHeight * 100 / body.clientHeight));
    return {
      height: body.clientHeight - header.clientHeight,
      percent: percent
    }
  }
}
```

After that i've created another helper to change the visual aspect of my modal when breakpoint reach 0.9:

```ts
export const setModalSheetContentHeight = (modal: HTMLIonModalElement, breakpoint: number, expand: boolean): any => {
  if (breakpoint >= 0.9 && !expand) {
    modal.classList.add('no-radius');
    modal.setCurrentBreakpoint(1);
    expand = true;
  } else if (breakpoint <= 0.9 && expand) {
    modal.classList.remove('no-radius');
    expand = false;
  }
  return expand;
}
```

The boolean "expand" avoid the helper to always set the modal breakpoint to 1.

Then i've created a method that add some listeners on the modal:

```ts
initModalListener(): void {
    let expand = false;
    // Define if the modal is fully expand
    const content = getContentHeight();
    // Return an object with content height in px and in %
    addEventListener('ionModalWillPresent', () => {
      this.modal.setAttribute('style', `--height: ${content.height}px`);
      // Set the modal height before it shown to avoid visual bug
    });
    addEventListener('ionBreakpointDidChange', (e: any) => {
      const breakpoint = e.detail.breakpoint;
      expand = setModalSheetContentHeight(this.modal, breakpoint, expand);
    });
  }
```

And after all of that i call this method inside of the method that create my modal:

```ts
 private async presentModal(): Promise<void> {
    this.modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: YourModalComponent,
      breakpoints: [0.3, 0.65, 1],
      initialBreakpoint: 0.3,
      backdropBreakpoint: 1,
      showBackdrop: false,
      canDismiss: false,
      keyboardClose: true,
      id: 'modalSheet',
      }
    });
    this.initModalListener();
    await this.modal.present();
  }
```

This is a first shot so i'm sure that there is plenty of thing to adjust but for now, it work pretty well with Ionic 6.